# If two points of intersection of a cubic and a line have real coordinates then so does the third.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $F\in \mathbb{R}[X,Y,Z]$ be a homogeneous cubic and let $C=V(F)\subset \mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}} ^2$. Let $P,Q\in C$ and let $L$ be the line through $P$ and $Q$. Suppose that $R$ is the third point of intersection of $L$ and $C$. How do I show that if $P,Q$ have real coordinates then so does $R$?

I was thinking of showing that $R$ is equal to its complex conjugate, but I could not do it.

Answer (score 4):

So, if $F$ is a homogenous cubic we can dehomogenize and look at it in the affine space $\mathbb{R}^2$ (after making sure to move the points $P, Q,$ and $R$ away from infinity).  Then you are given that $F$ has real coefficients, and $L$ will also have real coefficients.  The key fact will be that computing the intersection of $L$ and $V(F)$ gives you a degree three polynomial in one variable with real coefficients, two of whose solutions you know are real.  The third solution will then also be real, and this third solution is the third point in the intersection of $L$ and $V(F)$.